# Create childrens on rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rake-task

I have many rake scripts named example1_task, example1_task2 ... etc. I like to convert this scripts into once and use example1:task1, example1:task2 like i do with the command rake db:migrate on rails migrations.

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use namespace:

```
namespace "example" do
 task :task1 do 
    #some code
 end
 task :task2 do 
    #some code
 end
end
```